# My Form redirects to thankyou page but does not send me information submitted

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, cdo.message

I was asked to update this question to the most recent code and error. I now receive no error but the information from the form is still not being sent to the email. The asp is on the same page as the form:

The asp code:

```
<!--METADATA TYPE="typelib" UUID="CD000000-8B95-11D1-82DB-00C04FB1625D" NAME="CDO for Windows Library" -->

<!--METADATA TYPE="typelib" UUID="00000205-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4" NAME="ADODB Type Library" -->

<%
sectionID=8

frmName = request.Form("frmName")
frmEmail = request.Form("frmEmail")
frmPhone = request.Form("frmPhone")
frmAddress = request.Form("frmAddress")
frmReferral = request.Form("frmReferral")
frmCallback = request.Form("frmCallback")
frmEnquiry = request.Form("frmEnquiry")

if len(frmName) = 0 then
    errormessage = "<p><b style=""color: red"">Name field left blank.</b></p>"
elseif len(frmEmail) = 0 then
    errormessage = "<p><b style=""color: red"">E-mail field left blank.</b></p>"
elseif len(frmPhone) = 0 then
    errormessage = "<p><b style=""color: red"">Phone field left blank.</b></p>"
end if

if request.TotalBytes <> 0 and len(errormessage) = 0 then

    if len(frmReferral) = 0 then frmReferral = "(left blank)" end if
    if len(frmCallback) = 0 then frmCallback = "(left blank)" end if
    if len(frmAddress) = 0 then frmAddress = "(left blank)" end if
    if len(frmEnquiry) = 0 then frmEnquiry = "(left blank)" end if

    'send email
    '----------


SUB sendmail( frmName, frmEmail, frmPhone, frmAddress, frmReferral, frmCallback, frmEnquiry )   

Dim objCDO

Dim iConf

Dim Flds    

Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2  

    Set objCDO = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")

Set iConf = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")    

Set Flds = iConf.Fields

With Flds

.Item(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPickup

.Item(cdoSMTPServer) = "213.171.216.21"

.Item(cdoSMTPServerPort) = 25

.Item(cdoSMTPconnectiontimeout) = 10

.Update

End With


Set objCDO.Configuration = iConf

    objCDO.To = "user@domainname.com"
    objCDO.Subject = "Enquiry Form"

     bodyHTML =  "Name:" & vbcrlf _
                & frmName & vbcrlf _
                & vbcrlf _
                & "Email:" & vbcrlf _
                & frmEmail & "" & vbcrlf _
                & vbcrlf _
                & "Phone:" & vbcrlf _
                & frmPhone & "" & vbcrlf _
                & vbcrlf _
                & "Address:" & vbcrlf _
                & frmAddress & "" & vbcrlf _
                & vbcrlf _
                & "How did you hear about us?:" & vbcrlf _
                & frmReferral & "" & vbcrlf _
                & vbcrlf _
                & "Do you require a callback?:" & vbcrlf _
                & frmCallback & "" & vbcrlf _
                & vbcrlf _
                & "Enquiry:" & vbcrlf _
                & frmEnquiry

    'response.Write(bodyHTML)
    'response.End

    objCDO.TextBody = bodyHTML  


objCDO.Send

END SUB

    Set objCDO = Nothing

    Set iConf = Nothing

Set Flds = Nothing

    response.Redirect("contact-thankyou.asp")

end if %>
```

The form:

```
<form action="contact.asp" method="post">
                    <table  border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" class="text">
                        <tr>
                            <td><p>Name : * </p></td>
                            <td><input name="frmName" id="frmName" type="text" class="textbox" value="<%=frmName%>" size="35" title="Required" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><p>Email : *</p></td>
                            <td><input name="frmEmail" id="frmEmail" type="text" class="textbox" value="<%=frmEmail%>" size="35" title="Required" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><p>Phone : *</p></td>
                            <td><input name="frmPhone" id="frmPhone" type="text" class="textbox" value="<%=frmPhone%>" size="35" title="Required" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><p>Address :</p></td>
                            <td><input name="frmAddress" id="frmAddress" type="text" class="textbox" value="<%=frmAddress%>" size="35" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><p>How did you hear about us :</p></td>
                            <td><select name="frmReferral" id="frmReferral" class="block" style="width: 180px">
                            <option value=""> - SELECT - </option>
                            <option value="Magazine advert"<%if frmReferral = "Magazine advert" then%> selected="true"<%end if%>>Magazine advert</option>
                            <option value="Booklet advert"<%if frmReferral = "Booklet advert" then%> selected="true"<%end if%>>Booklet advert</option>
                            <option value="Web search"<%if frmReferral = "Web search" then%> selected="true"<%end if%>>Web search</option>
                            <option value="Web directory"<%if frmReferral = "Web directory" then%> selected="true"<%end if%>>Web directory</option>
                            <option value="Newspaper"<%if frmReferral = "Newspaper" then%> selected="true"<%end if%>>Newspaper</option>
                            <option value="TV"<%if frmReferral = "TV" then%> selected="true"<%end if%>>TV</option>
                            <option value="Other"<%if frmReferral = "Other" then%> selected="true"<%end if%>>Other</option>
                            </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><p>Do you require a call back :</p></td>
                            <td><select name="frmCallback" id="frmCallback" class="block" style="width: 180px">
                            <option value=""> - SELECT - </option>
                            <option value="Morning"<%if frmCallback = "Morning" then%> selected="true"<%end if%>>Morning</option>
                            <option value="Afternoon"<%if frmCallback = "Afternoon" then%> selected="true"<%end if%>>Afternoon</option>
                            <option value="Not Required"<%if frmCallback = "Not Required" then%> selected="true"<%end if%>>Not Required</option>
                            </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" valign="top"><p>Enquiry :</p></td>
                            <td><textarea name="frmEnquiry" id="frmEnquiry" cols="27" rows="4" class="textbox" style="width: 180px"><%=frmEnquiry%></textarea></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align="right"><input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Send " class="submit">
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input name="reset" type="reset" class="submit"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                </form>
```

Would appreciate any further assistance with this. Thanks

Comment: Please clean your question by having only the relevant and most recent code, then add the full exact error you get.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have cleaned up the question, I do not seem to be getting an error message the email just does not go through.

Answer (score 1):

There is no call to **sendmail** procedure.
Call the procedure.
e.g. *after the `'send email` comment line*.

```
'send email
'----------
Call sendmail( frmName, frmEmail, frmPhone, frmAddress, frmReferral, frmCallback, frmEnquiry )
```

**Update:**
Remove the following lines, all of these properties are completely fictitious :). These variables have already been in the variable `bodyHTML`.

```
objCDO.Name = frmName 
objCDO.Phone = frmPhone 
objCDO.Address = frmAddress 
objCDO.Referral = frmReferral 
objCDO.Callback = frmCallback 
objCDO.Enquiry = frmEnquiry
```

Comment: I added this line after the send email comment line and this still gives the same response without sending any information.

Comment: I added this after the comment line and before the sub sendmail. When uploading it to the host it shows up as a 500 server error. On the IIS server it shows up as a vb script error.

Comment: Need more details :) Firstly, update the question with a new section that contains error details. And configure your site to show detailed asp errors (This process varies according to versions of IIS, you can tell us which one is you on).

Comment: I have updated the question that shows the error details, I am on version 7.5 of IIS. Thanks

Comment: I removed the lines and received an error that said from had to be specified so I added in objCDO.From = frmEmail and received a new error which I updated above.

Comment: There was not `objCDO.From` in the will be removed lines list already. That error, could be several reasons. See the instructions : http://goo.gl/PfQZZ

Comment: Okay I'll go through the instructions I have posted the error I receive after I remove the objCDO.From

Comment: I have gone through the instructions but this doesn't help. Not sure what to do, I appreciate all your help though :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have more than you need in the configuration section.  Can you try it without the configuration items or do you need those?  I would try a simple send script and then expand it from there.

Here is a reference where I got what is below as well as other ways to send the email via CDO: [VBScript Email References](http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cdo.htm)

```
Const cdoSendUsingPickup = 1 'Send message using the local SMTP service pickup directory. 
Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2 'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network). 

Const cdoAnonymous = 0 'Do not authenticate
Const cdoBasic = 1 'basic (clear-text) authentication
Const cdoNTLM = 2 'NTLM

Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
objMessage.Subject = "Example CDO Message" 
objMessage.From = "test@test.com"
objMessage.To = "user@hotmail.co.uk"
objMessage.TextBody = "This is some sample message text.." & vbCRLF & "It was sent using SMTP authentication."

'==This section provides the configuration information for the remote SMTP server.

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 

'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "mail.your.com"

'Type of authentication, NONE, Basic (Base64 encoded), NTLM
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic

'Your UserID on the SMTP server
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "youruserid"

'Your password on the SMTP server
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "yourpassword"

'Server port (typically 25)
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 

'Use SSL for the connection (False or True)
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False

'Connection Timeout in seconds (the maximum time CDO will try to establish a connection to the SMTP server)
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

'==End remote SMTP server configuration section==

objMessage.Send
```